# WSL Stopped working with error: 0x80070003

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

WSL2 stopped working. When, I do a new installation of linux distro, it throws the following error on click of the launch button:

```
Installing, this may take a few minutes...
WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x80070003
Error: 0x80070003 The system cannot find the path specified.

Press any key to continue...
```

the `wsl --help` command works fine
however `wsl -l` command and other wsl commands throw the following error

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Comment: Also got same error, still no respond from M$

Comment: I am also having the exact same issue, did you solve that?

Comment: having the same issue using a fresh install from dev channel:
Edition Windows 10 Pro
Version Dev
Installed on ‎5/‎21/‎2021
OS build 21382.1
Experience Windows 10 Feature Experience Pack 321.12100.0.3
I also did an in-place upgrade using the iso as stated here: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/6363
No success...

Answer (score 10):

Check if you have any `.wslconfig` inside your profile in `%USERPROFILE%` folder and delete it! I finally got it working

FIY: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/3232#issuecomment-777023885

Comment: why isn't this written anywhere else?! I couldn't run Docker Desktop because of this, installed reinstall multiple times turned on and off the windows features! thanks for your comment!!.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same issue and it was due to my bad attempt at deleting the installed Distro. If yours is the same case, this should be pretty easy to fix, use the `wsl --unregister <DISTRO_NAME>` which in my case was debian so `wsl --unregister debian` unregistered the old path for the Debian executable and then I installed Debian again. This worked for my personal case but I thought it might help someone on the internet.

Comment: Indeed, this was the right answer for me. I had a previous installation of debian which I properly badly uninstalled. Basically `wsl --list` was showing it although I definitely removed it. So when clicking on the Open button in the Microsoft Store, the OP's message was showing. De-registering it and re-cliking on the Open button triggered a proper reinstall !